# Inserting null value into geometry column using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to insert a null value into a geometry column, which I cannot do:

> ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry

So what I'm trying to accomplish is to erase a point from a map and save that information - the deletion of the point - to the database.

I am new to spatial data and all I can find from the internet is how to insert points, polygons and whatnot, but not how to remove that information.

The table where the geometry column resides has other information as well, so removing a row is not something I can do.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange.com. Your table have geometry constraints implemented by [Populate_Geometry_Columns](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/Populate_Geometry_Columns.html), to ensure. To allow other to get you a better answer, could you please explain why you need to NULL some geometries? Maybe ther is another way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE "table" SET the_geom = NULL
```

This will work unless you have a NOT NULL-constraint on the geom-column.

Answer (score 5):

Common approach when creating *spatial tables* is ensure that certain constraints are accomplished. This common constraints can be checked in the documentation of [populate_geometry_columns](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/Populate_Geometry_Columns.html).

One of these constraints is add to the geometry field a NOT NULL check. If you **really** need a table that admits null geometries you can remove the constraint for that table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column DROP NOT NULL;
```

But have null geometries is usually a bad idea, because some software can have problems handling it. Depending on your use case probably a better idea is have another table that keeps the removed points.

Answer (score -2):

It's maybe better to remove unnecessary points rather than setting a 'NULL' geometry.

To delete a point (the entire row will be deleted) you can use an expression like that:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id_point = 'xxxx';
```

if the ID column is an integer :

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id_point = xxxx;
```

You must specify a WHERE clause otherwise your table will be empty.

Comment: why nor "ALTER TABLE xx add deleted boolean set  default false" and "UPDATE TABLE xx SET deleted = true WHERE ...

Comment: Right ! I think that I didn't understand the problem...   after this sentence "so removing a row is not something I can do"   delete query are adapted.